# Writing a list of dictionaries to multiple columns (and rows)

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of dictionaries of length `n`. Typical contents are:

```
[{"description":"Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit amet","error":"text_too_long"},{'description':'Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis','error':'text_too_long'},...]
```

I'm trying to write this to a CSV file, where "description" and "error" form two columns, and the rows are each element of the list.

I've tried:

```
import csv, ast
list_ = list_of_dictionaries #as a string
with open('data.csv','wb') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f)
    for string in list_:
        dictionary = ast.literal_eval(string) #converting to dictionary
        to_write = [dictionary["description"],dictionary["error"]]
        wtr.writerow([to_write])
```

This merely gives me the entire dictionary in a single column (but rows are fine). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen the https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter dictwriter class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries can be set directly, you do not need the `ast` function.

```
for dictionary in list_:
    to_write = [dictionary["description"],dictionary["error"]]
    wtr.writerow(to_write) # Not [to_write]
```

will write the dictionary in 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use `pandas`?

```
data = [{"description":"Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit amet","error":"text_too_long"},{'description':'Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis','error':'text_too_long'}]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You get this:

```
df
Out[246]: 
                       description          error
0    Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit amet  text_too_long
1  Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis  text_too_long
```

And then use `to_csv`:

```
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```